# Error when I try to close MySQL connection

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

When I try to close a MySQL connection, my page shows up as blank. Am I placing the closing of the connection in the right place? The user logs in (which is working), but then there seems to be an error with closing the MySQL connection in the userprofile.jsp. I think it is something to do with the closing of the connection as it is working without it

Login class which redirects to the userprofile page

```
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        MyDb1 db = new MyDb1();
      Connection con = db.getCon();
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select uid,name,pass from lauraccc_fyp.register where email = '"+name+"' and  pass = '"+pass+"'");

     while ((rs.next())) {

        String uid = rs.getString("uid");


             HttpSession session=request.getSession(); 
          session.setAttribute("name",uid);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/userprofile.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
         return;



  } catch (SQLException ex) {
       }




</head>
<body>

<div class="fh5co-loader"></div>

<%

try {

    String session_id =null;
    HttpSession session1=request.getSession(false); 

    if(session1!=null) {  
        session_id=(String)session1.getAttribute("name");  
    }

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lauraccc_fyp", "lauraccc", "*");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from register where uid='"+session_id+"'");
    rs.next();

    String name = rs.getString("name");
    con.close();

}catch(Exception e) {
    out.println(e);
}
<h1>Welcome back <%out.print(name);%></h1>
%>
```

Comment: place it in finally block after catch, after you close Statement and Resultset

Comment: I cannot place it after catch, as the con is declare in the try and not recognised after the catch

Answer (score 0):

Your page is blank?  I think this is because everything is fine.  In your try catch block, there is no output at all.

Comment: I outputting the name futher on... <h1>Welcome back <%out.print(name);%></h1>

Comment: Then your page should not be blank...  What is your complete source file?  And generated html page?